# win7 default user login on Domain

Tags: domain, login, windows-7

I was wondering if there is a way besides in the registry to keep the last username from showing up on a new log in for a win7 computer on a domain.

We have a few laptops that keep defaulting back to administrator upon new login and I found that you can modify this registry key

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
dontdisplaylastusername

I am just curious if there is an alternative to making the log in box blank besides there. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a GPO to manage this behavior. It toggles the same registry key, but it's much easier to manage. It's in the security policy section under Computer policy.

Answer (score 3):

There is a group policy item that can be set, either locally or from a domain controller:

To do it on the PC, run gpedit.msc, browse to Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Local Policies -> Security Options and look for 'Interactive login: Do not display last user name' and set it to 'enabled'.

Answer (score 1):

If these computers are in fact joined to a Windows AD domain then you can set this in Group Policy.

Computer Configuration>Windows Settings>Security Settings>Local Policies>Security Options>Interactive logon:Do not display last user name.

Note that this is a computer setting and needs to be set in the GPO that applies to the computer.